# Activity view not getting set when launched with FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-activity

I have a "main" activity. In the `onCreate()` method I'm calling `setContentView()`. Now while this main activity is on top I get a notification. In the notification I'm setting "main" as the intent to be invoked on click. Here I'm setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag.

On click event of notification I can see that `onNewIntent()` of main is getting called, from `onNewIntent()` I'm launching another activity `showData`. What I can see is that on click event of notification, the orientation of the screen changes but I'm still in the notification drop down menu. (Neither main or `showData` screen is visible). The orientation changes because the `showData` has orientation landscape as fixed. Now if I press back, I can see the `showData` screen.

This issue happens when main activity is on top while clicking the notification. If in any other activity, `showData` is getting displayed correctly.

Thanks a lot for your answer and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was launching the `showData` using this: `new Intent(main.this, showData.class)`.

I changed `main.this` to `getApplicationContext()` and now it is working fine.

Comment: Your 24 hours have passed. Please accept your own answer. Thanks!